# jqGrid: Calling functions from within cells, running on Railo

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jqgrid, railo

I have a series of jqGrid reports that loop a resultset to set the rows within cells.  Some cells have helper functions that are called from their cell.  These are user defined functions called from inside the cell data itself.

In ColdFusion, functions CAN be called from within cells, no problem.

In Railo, these function calls throw an error.  The error in the console is "SyntaxError: Unexpected Token".

To clarify, this ONLY applies to user defined functions.  I can call CF/Railo-defined functions like "trim()" or "evaluate()".

Any ideas on how to fix... or work-arounds?  Whether doing something differently with jqGrid or else a way to succesfully call functions in Railo (i.e. a different way).  I've tried wrapping the user defined function within an evaluate() and a few other small attempts, all to no avail..

Comment: Are you referring to CF functions or javascript functions?

Comment: CF (or Railo) functions from within the cell, a hypothetical example cell:  ["#myFunction(varX,varY)#"].  This WORKS in ColdFusion.  It errors in Railo as mentioned above.

Comment: 1 more post of clarification:  Building out data with json.  Also, CF/Railo functions work in either language, example respective to above would be:  ["#evaluate(varX+varY)#"] or ["#trim(varX)#"].  It's just user defined Railo functions that are not working (and it works in Cold Fusion!).

Comment: Compare the JSON that is being returned from your CF server versus your Railo server.  What is different?